# ADAL token caching fails in iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, adal

I am "suddenly" (after an update?) experiencing 2 new issues when authenticating  using the ADAL (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory) library in my iOS Xamarin application that was previously working fine.

I have tried rolling the version back to what was working previously, or alternatively moving up to the latest stable version but the issues persist.  Here is the code I am using.

```
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri)
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new Uri(returnUri),
            new PlatformParameters(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController));
        return authResult;
    }
```

The first issue is that when successfully authenticating the library fails to cache the returned token(s).  During the call to AcquireTokenAsync() I observe the following output in the Debug window:-

```
AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition started:
    Authority: https://login.windows.net/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/
    Resource: XXXX
    ClientId: XXXX
    CacheType: null
    Authentication Target: User

TokenCache.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
TokenCache.cs: No matching token was found in the cache
TokenCache.cs: Storing token in the cache...
TokenCache.cs: An item was stored in the cache
AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
```

It then seems to attempt to write the token to the cache but I see the following in the debug window:-

```
TokenCachePlugin.cs: Failed to remove cache record: -34018
TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
TokenCachePlugin.cs: Failed to save cache record: -34018[0:] Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJ…
```

Then the next time I start the application and call this method I observe the following output:-

```
 - AuthenticationContext.cs: ADAL PCL.iOS with assembly version '3.13.9.1126', file version '3.13.9.1126' and informational version 'eddfa8ebda9e734efdc42ea6d41ea98bc7c998f3' is running...
xxxxxxx-7318-4ec7-xxxx-7xxxxxxx42c2 - AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition started:

    Authority: https://login.windows.net/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/
    Resource: XXXX
    ClientId: XXXX
    CacheType: null
    Authentication Target: User

TokenCache.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
TokenCache.cs: No matching token was found in the cache
```

There seems to be no further information around on how to interpret this that I can find?  The thing is this code was working fine previously, however I think it has stopped working possibly afer an upgrade to XCode on my mac.  I am developing on a Parallels VM with VS2017.

Therefore every time I start the app I need to login again.  I have seen this reported elsewhere but have not found a resolution.  Is there a clue in the “CacheType: null” output maybe?

The second issue is that the call to AcquireTokenAsync() seems to not return when the user selects “Cancel” on the login screen - ie the “return authResult;” line never gets hit - unless I actually successfully authenticate.  Is that expected, or am I maybe using the library incorrectly in both instances?

Comment: I had been facing the same issue, did you find a solution for token caching in iOS?.

Comment: Can we store TokenCache Authority in a local cache and use it from our code? is it worth?